# take user input and use that for a program

Tags: python, numbers

I am new to python and this is just for personal knowledge.

So how would I design a program to take a number input N from the user and print out all the numbers from 0 to N ..

Comment: FYI: the first google result brought me there. Plesae do some research

Comment: its not what I want , not even close @ThomasWeller

Comment: Then please explain what you already have and how your question differs from that.

Comment: i simply want a program that takes a number input from a user and prints out all the number from 0 to that number. that question is only about inputing numbers @ThomasWeller

Comment: Thomas is right this is a duplicate. If you want to know how to print from 0 to n, research about the `range` function.

Comment: FYI: fist google result for search terms "print numbers from 0 to n python"

Comment: Yeah, I know. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

This one works

```
n = int(input("enter a number"))
counts = 0
print (0)
while counts != n:
    counts += 1
    print(counts)
    if counts == n:
        break
```